# “Allow full disk access for remote users” checkbox not appearing for remote login

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, ssh, remote-desktop

I have been using a spare mac-mini (late 2012 model) running Catalina 10.15.7 as a general use home server, mostly for running plex, and have it plugged in and not connected to a monitor. As a result my only ways of accessing it has been through ssh and with VNC viewer for anything that is particularly unwieldy to do through the command line.

After noticing that I was having issues executing some commands I looked online and saw that I needed to select the “Allow full disk access for remote users” checkbox, however upon looking at the sharing page there is blank space where the checkbox should be.

I have tried restarting and have made sure that sshd-keygen-wrapper have full disk access (it did) and I still cannot see the checkbox or execute some commands.

If anyone knows what the issue is here I would greatly appreciate some guidance!

[image: Sharing settings page without “Allow full disk access for remote users” checkbox]

Comment: I found this - https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2021/09/29/enabling-full-disk-access-for-ssh-on-macos-big-sur-using-a-management-profile/ - can't test. It apparently only appears for locally logged-in users, which is something I've seen on other settings, so the alternative would be a to hook up a screen temporarily.

Comment: I also don't know whether this was new to Catalina or Big Sur. It doesn't exist in Mojave.

Comment: I use ssh to login to an Administrator account on a 2013 iMac running Catalina. I also use Screen Sharing. I have never had problems running commands. Some commands require `sudo`. Have you tried executing the commands remotely while also connected by Screen Sharing. Maybe there is a popup where you need to give permission.